# Is there a way to only return fields defined within a Mongoose schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, find, schema

Let's say I have a collection `People` with the following document inside:

```
{
   "name": "John",
   "age": 25,
   "gender": "male"
}
```

And two Schemas for the document, one that should return all the information, and another that should only return a subset of the information:

```
var Person = mongoose.Schema({ "name": String, "age": Number, "gender": String}, {collection: "People");
var PersonName = mongoose.Schema({ "name": String }, {collection: "People"});
```

How do I get `PersonName` to only return name?

Currently, I have a document with a lot of unnecessary information, and would like to only return a subset of the data when using `.find()`. I have defined a schema and set it's collection manually. Going against the defined Schema, it returns all fields.

Comment: Do you have any answer on this? I have been manually set the schema with "select: false" in my RefSchema. But some of the schemas are going too big to do it manually. Will need to maintain 2 or more schemas if fields are changed.

Answer (score 1):

no need to define another schema to get specific property from a collection. Just specify which properties you want to return in `find()` function as projection option.

```
Schema.find(query,options,callbackFunction);
```

like:

```
person.find({},{name:1}, function(err, docs) {//used name:1 to return only name
   if(error) {
      return res.status(400).send({msg: "error"});
   }
   return res.status(200).send(docs);
});
```

Comment: This would work, but is there a way to just have it pull from the Schema, as my Schema has nested fields and is a bit more complex than the example I provided.

Comment: you can select nested object like `{"name.firstName":1}` in projection option. However you should provide actual problem in question then we can provide perfect solution otherwise how you expect perfect solution.:)

Comment: its not good idea define multiple schema to get some fields from a schema. (my opinion)

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea of using "select: false" on the Reference schema. We still have to list/define all the related fields.

For example,

```
{
   "name": "John",
   "age": 25,
   "gender": "male"
}
```

```
var Person = mongoose.Schema({ "name": String, "age": Number, "gender": String}, {collection: "People");
var PersonRef = mongoose.Schema({ "name": String, "age": { type: Number, select: false }, "gender": { type: String, select: false },} {collection: "People"});
```

But this method will only applicable (or useful) when the schema is relatively small for maintainability. If the schema grown bigger, then we will need to set `select: false` in both (or multiple schema) to avoid auto select in RefSchema.

I'm still looking for a better solution to handle this.